# How to turn LINQ query into anonymous type

Tags: c#, linq

I'm having such a brain fail. I have selected the elements and the values I need, I am just struggling with making this return an anonymous type:

Here is the XML:

```
<r25:space xl:href="space.xml?space_id=244" id="BRJDMjQ0" crc="00000023" status="est">
  <r25:space_id>244</r25:space_id>
  <r25:space_name>BEC*103</r25:space_name>
  <r25:formal_name>Branson Education Center 103</r25:formal_name>
  <r25:partition_id />
  <r25:partition_name />
  <r25:favorite>F</r25:favorite>
  <r25:max_capacity>24</r25:max_capacity>
  <r25:fill_ratio />
  <r25:last_mod_user>kleierd</r25:last_mod_user>
  <r25:last_mod_dt>2009-11-19T15:35:33</r25:last_mod_dt>
</r25:space>
```

I need the value of "space_id" and "space_name" which I can get with this:

```
var ids = from id in xml.Descendants()
                  where id.Name.LocalName == "space_id" || id.Name.LocalName == "space_name"
                  select (string)id.Value;
```

But I would really like it like this:

```
var ids = from id in xml.Descendants()
                  where id.Name.LocalName == "space_id" || id.Name.LocalName == "space_name"
                  select new
                  { 
                      theId = //The id val would go here,
                      theName = //The name goes here
                  };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var ids = from id in xml.Descendants()
          where id.Name.LocalName == "space_id" || id.Name.LocalName == "space_name"
          select new
          { 
                theId = id.Value,
                theName = id.Name.LocalName
          };
```

ids will hold values:

```
theId     theName 
244       pace_id 
BEC*103   space_name
```

this will select the same nodes:

```
XNamespace r25 = "yourSchemaDefinition";

var ids = xml.Descendants(r25 + "space_id")
             .Union(xml.Descendants(r25 + "space_name"))
             .Select(id => new
                           { 
                              theId = id.Value,
                              theName = id.Name.LocalName
                           });
```

NOTE: I've added `r25` schema definition to your xml root node